# Cannot get data in HTML

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning, lightninginput

With this code, I get my data, it is visible in the console, however I think I made an error in HTML because I can't display anything, a little help please Please on how to fix this, I want to display my data (Get the value of the field name of each input) .
==> JS

```
 @wire(getObj, { recordId: '$recordId'}) 
    getObj({error,data}){
        if (data) {
            console.log('My data is '+JSON.stringify(data));
        this.OBJS= data;
        this.OBJS.forEach(obj=> {
                                            this.objli.push({ 
                                                Account__c: obj.Id, 
                                               Family__c: 'Fuels',
                                               Unit__c: 'm3' 
                                            });

                                            this.objli.push({ 
                                              Account__c: obj.Id, 
                                                Family__c: 'Lubricants', 
                                                Unit__c: 'm3' });

        
  });
} else if (error) {
    console.log('An error has occurred:');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
}
 
}
```

==> HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <lightning-record-edit-form class="slds-col slds-size_8-of-8" object-api-name="Qualification__c">
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                             <th>{Label.lab1}</th>
                            <th>{Label.lab2}</th>
                            <th>{Label.lab3}</th>
                            <th>{Label.lab4}</th>
                            <th>{Label.lab5}</th>
                            <th>{Label.lab6}</th>
                            <th>{Label.lab7}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody for:each={OBJS} for:item="obj" key={obj.Id}>
 <td>{obj.Name}</td>
                            <td>
                                <lightning-input style=" width: 80%;margin-left: 10%;" type="number" id={obj.Id}
                                    name="Lub" onchange={handleYearChange}></lightning-input>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <lightning-input style=" width: 80%;margin-left: 10%;" type="text" disabled
                                    value={Label.Lub}></lightning-input>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <lightning-combobox style=" width: 80%;margin-left: 10%;" value={value}
                                    options={options} id={obj.Id} name="Lub" onchange={handleUnitChange}>
                                </lightning-combobox>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <lightning-input style=" width: 80%;margin-left: 10%;" type="number" id={obj.Id}
                                    name="Lub" onchange={handleObjChange}></lightning-input>
                            </td>
                          <td>
                                <lightning-input style="width: 80%;margin-left: 10%;" type="text" name="archivedValue"
                                  onchange={handleAchivedValue}></lightning-input>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <lightning-input style="width: 80%;margin-left: 10%;" type="text" name="progress"
                                onchange={handleProgress}></lightning-input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
</table>
            </div>
<br>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to iterate over an Object,

```
for:each={OBJS}
```

for the above to work, you need to pass in an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: what I get in my console as result for data is :   My data  is [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]